# What sizes of wood do I order from the timber yard?

Tags: wood

If any of you make toys (cars trains ships etc) what do you ask for in terms of timber dimensions when you go the timber yard please?
I assumed I would ask for 1” x 2”.   Or 1” x 3”  in 4’ lengths
But I don’t really know what sizes it comes in, nor what is the cheapest way to buy it.

I’m looking to use Beech, unless you recommend anything else.

Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: You are in UK yes? Ordering in different countries is different so it is good to specify. Beech is a good choice for toys and I think affordable in UK, much more expensive in America.

Comment: My brother made wood toys commercially for a few years; He picked up the end trims for free at the saw mill, mostly pine ( CA , US).

Comment: The use of the word "timber" and of imperial measurements in the same question is rather confusing. Imperial reads "USA", while "timber" reads "everywhere else in the world"...

Answer (score 1):

Ordering at the lumberyard is usually fairly dynamic.

You can go in with a list of what’s optimum, but then it always seems like something is unavailable in some dimension you want. (“No, we don’t have 8 footers, we have 12s.” “We don’t have 1x4, but we do have 1x6.”)

So I usually go in with both my optimum order and a detailed list of what makes that up. (And a knowledge that I can turn a 2x4 into a pair of 2x2s.) With the detailed list, I can (relatively) quickly recalculate based on what is actually available.

It’s a good idea to call in advance and see if the have stock of approximately what you’re looking for.

As far as cost, there usually isn’t an obvious way to save money, except in the case where you can pick through a lower graded stack of lumber and find pieces that will still work for you. Not all places are set up like that, though.

Last point: don’t completely write off the big box stores. Some have a decent supply of hardwood, and you can pick through the defects to find wood you can use. As a general rule, there are many many more useless boards there, compared to a good lumberyard, but you have the luxury of time.

Comment: OP says timber not lumber, so I think they are in UK.

Comment: @VolframK -- fair enough... I don't remember the B&Q having anything nice, but it's been a while... I will leave the last paragraph in for North American readers.

Comment: ...and the BigBox store will charge _substantially more_ for the wood.

Comment: Agreed with @gnicko: I just picked up some poplar for a project at my local lumber yard for $4.50/board-foot. The equivalent (though S4S) at my big-box would be about $12/board-foot. For that price, I'll spend some time wood _working_.